# How to jsonignore a field based on depth level during deserialization

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, pojo

I have a specific field in a class that I want to ignore if the class depth is more than 2. So if the class is too deeply nested I want to ignore only field of the nested class.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such annotation. If it is OK for your case you can first parse the whole string to a JsonNode object and then remove the child nodes programmatically.

Comment: A code example would help here.